# Resource allocation with minimal differences

Tags: probability-distributions, order-theory

Let $N$ be a finite set. Let $\prec$ be a strict partial order over $N$. I am interested in designing a function $f : N \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $\sum_{n_i \in N} f(n_i) = 1$
- $\forall i,j : n_i \prec n_j \implies f(n_i) < f(n_j)$

...and minimizing the maximum of pairwise differences $| f(n_i) - f(n_j) |$.

I am also interested in the case with an additional constraint:

- $\forall i,j : | f(n_i) - f(n_j) | > k$

In this second case, an important question is, given $(N, \prec)$, for which values of $k$ does the problem have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $\{0,1\}$ with order $0\prec 1$. Then we can construct an $f$ with an arbitrarily small pairwise difference $2\epsilon$ by letting $$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       .5-\epsilon &  x=0 \\
       .5+\epsilon &  x=1
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

So there is no unique optimum.

For the second part, suppose we have a total order. Then we imagine placing $x_1,x_2,\dots$ at $0,k,2k,\dots$. This is clearly the solution which has the smallest total size.

The total size is $\sum_{i=0}^{|N|}ik$, so a solution will exist for $k$ where this sum is less than 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected this might be an issue, hence the subquestion with the additional constraint. Any idea on a general construction in that case?

Comment: @Philippe: see my edit.